# R - differences between plotting in and without loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, quantmod

I have quite strange problem with R. I want to plot some charts of stock. Everything works fine, except of Bollinger Bands - BBands. - plot contains only series, not bands. This happens only when I plot in loop. When I tried to plot it without loop, like in the end of my code, it was ok.

EDIT//I just noticed that it also happens with Aroon, SMI, CVL and MACD.

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

getSymbols( Symbols="AAPL", src="yahoo")
th=chartTheme('white');

funkcje=c('BBands','ChAD','CMF','MFI','CCI','MACD','RSI','ROC','TDI','Aroon','SMI','ADX','ATR','ChVol','CLV','DPO','EMV','KST','SAR','Volatility','WPR','ZigZag');

#everything works fine except for i=1 - BBands
for(i in 1:length(funkcje)){
  fun=get(paste0('add',funkcje[i]));
  cat(funkcje[i],'\n')
  pdf(paste0(funkcje[i],'.pdf'))
  chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", theme=th)
  fun();
  dev.off();
}

#this works fine
fun=get(paste0('add',funkcje[1]))
pdf(paste0(funkcje[1],'.pdf'))
chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", theme=th)
fun()
dev.off()
```

Comment: It is a quite good question. I met this question too without know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an issue with lazy evaluation. Try wrapping your call to `fun` in `print` to force evaluation.

```
for(i in 1:length(funkcje)){
  fun=get(paste0('add',funkcje[i]));
  cat(funkcje[i],'\n')
  pdf(paste0(funkcje[i],'.pdf'))
  chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", theme=th)
  print(fun())
  dev.off();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar problem using `chart_Series()`. Would just not plot inside a loop until I placed the `chart_Series()` inside an otherwise empty `plot()` function. The BBands do show if the same thing is done here. I reduced the studies to avoide margin issues on my graphics device and reduced flicker by moving the actual `chartSeries()` call outside of the loop:

```
getSymbols( Symbols="AAPL", src="yahoo")
th=chartTheme('white');

funkcje=c('BBands','ChAD','CMF','MFI','CCI','MACD');
chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", theme=th)
#everything works fine except for i=1 - BBands
for(i in 1:length(funkcje)){
    fun=get(paste0('add',funkcje[i]));
    plot(fun())
}
```

I hope this helps others looking to get their quantmod for/while loop to actually plot something.